# Execute bulk of scripts on different databases using single script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to execute bulk of scripts on a database server, i am able to execute it with the help of batch but This database server having multiple databases,so for every database i am writing below mentioned script-
EX-

for database name1-

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S [Server] /d [A] -E   -i"%%G" pause
```

for database name2-

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S [Server] /d [B] -E   -i"%%G" pause
```

is there any way so that i don't have to write this .bat file for every database name?i want to write single script which works for all the databases...

Comment: so is [server] and [A]/[B] actual values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your script to be:

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S %1 /d %2 -E   -i"%%G" pause
```

then pass in the server and database name when launching the bash script. For example, if your script was called "myscript.bat", then you could launch it from command line via

```
> myscript.bat server name
```

Comment: Can you please have a look on my updated question? actually database name doesn't follow any pattern..

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect what I believe you are trying to represent, however see my comment on you question.

Comment: thanks,it's working fine.i do have one more query..normally if i have to execute any folder's files i have to put my batch file there and there are many subfolders, so i have to paste my bat file in every folder..is there a way so that i have to place my bat file only at one location and it executes the subfolders files?

Comment: You should create a seperate question on here for that. Unfortunately im not extremely versed in batch scripting,  so i cant really answer that question,  but if my post answered the question in this thread,  please marke it as the correct answer and upvote it apropriately.  :)